# Why does stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset behave differently in "preview" and final page?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this svg circle that I want to have filled in X% based on the state of something (phone battery charge).

```
    <circle
       style="display:inline;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#323232;stroke-width:6;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="real_circle"
       cx="271.52206"
       cy="85.024849"
       r="28.786091" />
```

(Full svg from browser dev tools here: https://jsfiddle.net/mg508L34/)

As far as my research took me, t seems like I need to find the "real" radius (`r_real`). This would be `r_real = r - (stroke-width/2) = 28.786091 - (6/2) = 25.786091`. Meaning the circumference is `c = 2 * pi * r_real ~ 162`.

I am using [HA-floorplan](https://experiencelovelace.github.io/ha-floorplan/) (for [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/)), and this is the css (generated directly by javascript):

```
                  style: |
                    >
                    return `
                      stroke-dasharray: 162 162;
                      stroke-dashoffset: ${-(162*(entity.state/100))};
                      transform-box: fill-box;
                      transform-origin: center;
                      transform: rotate(180deg);
                    `;
```

I see in the page preview that it looks right (currently the charge state is 56%, and I'm trying to remove that much of the circle):

[image]

But if I save the config and load the "real" page, it looks completely off:

[image]

I haven't been able to get an answer on the forums for this specific software, since the people there (who have been helpful) are not css experts.

Any idea why it does this? Is it e.g. scaling the circle size too something that is not 28.786...? If so, how do I find the scaling factor, and is that different for different screen sizes (this will be seen on both computer and mobile). Or is it something else messing it up?

EDIT:

If I try to set a static `stroke-dashoffset` for the moment to make it easier and set it to -162*0.66 to simulate 66% charge (=-106.92), and look at the code I feed vs. what I see in the webpage dev tools, the following code:

```
          style: |
            >
            return `
              stroke-dasharray: 162 162;
              stroke-dashoffset: ${-(162*(.66))};
              transform-box: fill-box;
              transform-origin: center;
              transform: rotate(180deg);
            `;
```

results in the following when inspecting the web page (dev tools):

```
<circle style="display: inline; fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: rgb(50, 50, 50); stroke-width: 6px; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-dasharray: 162px, 162px; stroke-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer; stroke-dashoffset: -106.92px; transform-box: fill-box; transform-origin: center center 0px; transform: rotate(180deg);" id="real_circle" cx="271.52206" cy="85.024849" r="28.786091" inkscape:export-filename="/Users/mfd356/all-floors.png" inkscape:export-xdpi="300" inkscape:export-ydpi="300" class="floorplan-click floorplan-hover"><title>Battery Level
State: 75
```

So it looks like it retains the size of the circle, as well as the `stroke-dashoffset`. But I keep seeing what I showed in the screennshots above. So now I really have no clue why it renders differently on the web page.

EDIT 2:

I need to reveal something behind the circle, so e.g. 66% should remove 66% of the circle (starting from the left hand side, and going counter-clockwise), so it would show 66% of the figure below (only showing the green part when closer to 100%).

[image]

so something like this for 66%:

[image]

I also can't do something like `cx="50%"`, since each of 5 of these circles (in the end, when this part works) needs to be in 5 exact locations in a >300 object svg file.

EDIT 3:
The full svg from the browser dev tools ca be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/mg508L34/

Since it was mentioned in the comments that some other css might override, I looked at the associated css file and found this:

```css
svg, svg * {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke !important;
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

I tried adding `vector-effect: none`:

```
                    >
                    return `
                      stroke-dasharray: 162 162;
                      stroke-dashoffset: ${-(162*(.66))};
                      transform-box: fill-box;
                      transform-origin: center;
                      transform: rotate(180deg);
                      vector-effect: none;
                    `;
```

But this didn't help.

Comment: Please inspect your generated output in firefox/chromium dev tools and check if `stroke-dasharray` values are changed. You can copy the svg via rightclick and add it as a code snippet to your question. Apparently your app will apply additional scaling/conversions.

Comment: I've added the details. I (unfortunately) don't see anything that stands out to me though.

Comment: Your `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` needs to be adjusted according to the radius or circumference of your circle. In your preview the circle is significantly smaller than your actual rendered circle.

Comment: Please replace your code example with the complete svg output. Otherwise, we can't tell what's going on in your output. So please copy the `<svg>` element in dev tools. If it exceeds the post limit, jut add a codepen/jsfiddle link. There might be overriding group styles or global css rules. However, changing the radius will also require to adjust your dash length calculation, (r=28.786091 = stroke-dasharray="180.87 180.87"). If you can define the `<circle>` you should try `pathLength="100"` to simplify the calculations.

Comment: I've added a link to the full svg. I tried your first suggestion with `pathLength="100"` and no `stroke-dashoffset`, but that still looked wrong. I did notice something in the css file (also inserted under "EDIT 3").

Comment: @herrstrietzel, thanks for your pointer, it was something in css overwriting! Feel free to make your own answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @herrstrietzel's comment, I found the culprit. I had

```
svg, svg * {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke !important;
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

in my *.css file. While neither adding

```
svg circle#real_circle{
    vector-effect: none!important;
}
```

to the css file, or directly adding `vector-effect="none" !important` to the object helped (though I thought it should have), at least deleting the `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke !important;` did, so it was the problem.